# Full screen capture of a DirectX program in java (Javacv ?)

Tags: java, directx, screen, capture

[For Windows]
I know it is possible to capture screen of a DirectX program running under C# language, but do you know some sample code for Java?

I am actually facing this same problem than this [Take screen shots inside of full screen applications with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359754/take-screen-shots-inside-of-full-screen-applications-with-java?rq=1). Robot class didn't helped and neither worked.

But yet I didn't found any sample of java code on the internet concerning this. 
Thanks for any help you could provide on this topic.

Comment: See if [ScreenshotUsingPrintScreen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12251447/418556) produces a `mimetype=image/x-java-image;representationclass=java.awt.Image`.

Comment: Interesting, good way and idea to skirt the problem. After some quick check I got an error returned about the clipboard. Like if it was used by another process on Windows, I assume.

Comment: Solved it in assigning null to cb before the getSystemClipBoard, in this way it simply clear every pre Windows uses.

Comment: Anyway, I am still stuck. (dance)

Answer (score 2):

Since I worked on it more, see also:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class ClipboardScreenshot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // get the screenshot
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.delay(40);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.delay(404);

        Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        DataFlavor[] flavors = cb.getAvailableDataFlavors();
        System.out.println("After: ");
        for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
            System.out.println(flavor);
            if (flavor.toString().indexOf("java.awt.Image")>0) {
                Object o = cb.getData(flavor);
                Image i = (Image)o;
                // ImageIO will not write an Image
                // It will write a BufferedImage (a type of RenderedImage)
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                        i.getWidth(null),
                        i.getHeight(null),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
                g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
                g.dispose();

                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
                sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sp);
                File f = new File(
                        System.getProperty("user.home") + 
                        File.separator + 
                        "the.png");
                ImageIO.write(bi, "png", f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but actually not working for DirectX programs in Full screen. Just tried, didn't worked,no idea why yet. As if the key pressed and released was disabled.

Comment: Simulating the `PRINT_SCREEN` on `Ubuntu` launches the `ScreenShot Manager` application and the user has to press the `Copy to Clipboard` button on it to take it to clipboard.