# Fast screen capture using DirectX in Java (Re-writing from existing code in C# to Java)

Tags: c#, java, directx, url-rewriting, screenshot

My aim is to **capture the screen using DirectX in Java**.
 I have found the project fully detailed and explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274461/Very-fast-screen-capture-using-DirectX-in-Csharp) in C# .

Unfortunately, I do not have any knowledge in C sharp. I don't know if I can ask here a re-writing code above mentioned from C# to Java to those who handle both language, but I guess the final result would interest a lot of people.

Anyway, I thank those in advance who would be kind enough to help me with this. Even if I never tried, I know that a C# -> Java conversion software (or any other language) is not advised, explaining my question of ***re-writing***.

Please find on below the code concerned:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SlimDX.Direct3D9;

namespace KMPP
{
public class DxScreenCapture
{
    Device d;

    public DxScreenCapture()
    {
        PresentParameters present_params = new PresentParameters();
        present_params.Windowed = true;
        present_params.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
        d = new Device(new Direct3D(), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, IntPtr.Zero, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, present_params);
    }

    public Surface CaptureScreen()
    {
        Surface s = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(d, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Scratch);
        d.GetFrontBufferData(0, s);
        return s;
    }
}
}
```

---

PS:Since *Surface s* is here a DirectX type of image, it would be interesting for me then to convert it into PNG then.

Comment: Don't try to translate one to the other especially for this functionality as they work completely different for this action.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I know, this is why I asked for a re-writing code to those who handle both language.

Comment: I think you're going about this wrong. This won't require a "re-write" of code, but rather a completely different Java approach. Get rid of your C# code unless you wish to write a C# app.

Comment: If on the other hand you have C code dll that will do this functionality, then you could potentially use it directly in your Java application using JNI or JNA.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels: All right, but since few days non-stop looking for it on the internet, I didn't even found some sample code on this topic in java. But I found some C#, as mentioned above, which perfectly fit with my wishes. I didn't find other solutions but re-writing this. If you have any, I would be glad to read them, please,do not hesitate to let me know.

Comment: As HFOE said, you should approach this by creating a dll and then loading it via native methods in your Java application.

Comment: @ Vulcan: I see, even if I have yet no idea on how to do that, I need to inform myself on this field.

Comment: But not a .NET DLL, not with standard JNI or JNA (although there may be  utilities that can tie the two together, but I've never used them).

Comment: If you really need DirectX, I create a library using BridJ (https://bridj.googlecode.com) that wrap DirectX classes, so you can use almost the same code than C++ examples. You can find the library in https://bitbucket.org/fourthskyinteractive/directx-for-java. Please, let me know about projects you develop.

Answer (score -2):

### Java isn't C#

C# is totally different to java. C# can use `DirectX` but java cannot use it because DirectX was unavailable on all platforms. Instead you can use the `Robot` class present in `java.awt` package. Here's how to get the `image`.

### Doing it with a robot

```
Dimension ss = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Robot r = new Robot();
BufferedImage s = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(ss));
```

It returns a `BufferedImage` which contains the screenshot.

Comment: Java way, **not in this case**. As explained here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262448/full-screen-capture-of-a-directx-program-in-java-javacv), **the Robot class cannot capture fullscreen DirectX**, and this is what I am looking for. I only found this C# way for this aim.

Comment: @Arsenic: Yep, that's why I think your best bet is to find a C dynamic link library if you need this functionality and then link to it with JNA.

Comment: Try this. It shows you a java program which takes fullscreen screenshots. http://openwritings.net/public/java/take-screenshots-full-screen

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati That link has stopped working at some time during the past four years.